# Copy/Paste part of a file into another file using Terminal (or Shell)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, terminal, copy-paste

I am trying to copy part of a .txt file from the line number n to the line number n+y (let's say 1000 to 1000000).

I tried with operators and **sed**, and it failed. Here's the command I tried:

```
sed -n "1000, 1000000p" path/first/file > path/second/file
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the sed command you give in the example; in what way does it fail?

Comment: If the input file has incorrect line endings, you will need to convert them first. Try `dos2unix`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

if you know how many lines are in your source file (wc -l) you can do this .. assume 12000 lines and you want lines 2000 - 7000 in your new file (total of 5000 lines).

cat myfile | tail -10000 | head -5000 > newfile

Read the last 10k lines, then read the 1st 5k lines from that.

Comment: You do not need to know how many lines are in the file: simply put the head first.

Comment: And if you want to put the tail first, you can use `tail -n +2000`.  This also takes less buffer space.

Comment: Bling, Useless Use of Cat. Besides, the original `sed` command was just fine for this.

Comment: Thnx everybody for the answer, both the sed and the cad command worked ;).

Answer (score 3):

`sed` command should work fine, replace double quotes with single quotes.

```
sed -n '1000, 1000000p' path/first/file > path/second/file
```