# How do I resolve variables in command line

Tags: bash, shell

How do I take a text file, skip the first 14 records, skip the last 2 records, put everything else into a new file?

I can write a simple Java or python code to do this, but I am looking for even simpler bash script/command line.

Anyone can help me on this?

Comment: Look at head and tail, or sed

Comment: what do you mean by `14 records` ? how they differ from rest ?

Comment: Have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259658/copy-paste-part-of-a-file-into-another-file-using-terminal-or-shell/9259792#9259792

Answer (score 2):

You can do by using `awk`, if you wish to skip first N(14) and last M(2) lines

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v N="$(wc -l < inputfile.txt)" -v first_lines=14 -v last_lines=2 '{
    if (NR >= first_lines && NR <= N - last_lines) 
    print $0
}' inputfile.txt >> outfile.txt 2>&1
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Appending to the output file, not writing it from the beginning?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it appends from 15th line to last but 2 lines.let say lines 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 in inputfile.txt, if first 2 and last 2 filter, then outfile.txt  contains 3 4 5 6 lines.

Comment: This doesn't work; it outputs line x if 14 <= x <= 2 (which is never true). You need to know how many lines there are in total before you can skip the last *k* lines.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, Good Catch, Updated the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would a combination of `head` and `tail`:

```
# hf_filter - remove a header and footer of fixed length from the input
$ hf_filter () { tail -n +$(($1 + 1)) | head -n -$2; }
$ hf_filter 14 2 < old.txt > new.txt
```

However, this requires GNU `head`, as the standard version requires a positive integer as the argument for the `-n` option.

A solution to this problem requires buffering `$last` lines of output or prior knowledge of the length of the input. (GNU `head` does the buffering for you.) A standard `awk` solution might look like

```
awk -v h=14 -v t=2 'NR > h {buf[NR]=$0; s=NR-t} s in buf {print buf[s]; delete buf[s]}' old.txt > new.txt
```

The `delete buf[s]` isn't strictly necessary, but I think it should keep the memory usage constant (although I don't really know how `awk` manages memory allocations internally).

If you don't mind reading the input twice, you can get the input length if you don't already know it.

```
# Quotes are necessary; wc outputs leading spaces that break the assignment otherwise
awk -v n="$(wc -l < old.txt)" h=14 t=2 'NR > h && NR < n - t' old.txt > new.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use sed:

```
lines=$(wc -l < inputfile)                                            
sed -n "15,$((lines-1))p" inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: This is the inverse of what was requested; it outputs the lines that should be skipped.

Comment: You are right, my original "solution" was the opposite of what OP wants. I updated my answer.